# Win32 - Get permission to save file to C drive

Tags: file, winapi, permissions, uac, privileges

I have a program that the user can save the output session to a text file. This works fine, but when I try to save the file to a location such as `C:\`, it shows an error dialog saying:

`You don't have permission to save to this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission. Would you like to save to the Documents folder instead?`

When I click no, thinking it would just cancel the operation, my application crashes.
I do not want my application to *require* administrative privileges, but how, when attempting to save the file, do I ask the user to provide privileges (such as bring up the UAC dialog, and if required provide authentication). If the user cannot provide the permissions I would like to just stay on the Save File Dialog until the user either picks a location they have permission to save to, or presses cancel. I do not really want the permission to be asked for when the program starts, just when the user saves the file to a location they need permission for.

By the way I am currently logged in as administrator when running my application, it's the only account on my computer running Windows Vista.

Comment: If you press No, then I expect its returning the unchanged path to `c:\blah`. Your application then tries to write to this and fails, for which the solution is proper error handling. How depends on what language and environment you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications elevate only at startup. To simulate "getting UAC privs while running and only if needed" you actually need to partition your app so that it launches a second process (for example, to write to the file) and this process might be launched elevated. You can do this, but it's a lot of work for little or no benefit.

The whole point of UAC is to change the way users and applications treat the hard drive. The root of C is not a smart place to write things. Use AppData, or Documents, or create your own folder like C:\MySpecialApp (add the path to a config file) and write there. If you insist on writing to the root of C, then you require admin privs which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ah, I see. And my application itself is not trying to write to a configuration located in the C root. I was testing my program which is a calculator, the part where the user can specify a text file to export the variables, linear functions, and calculations made. I only tried saving the file to C:\ to see what would happen. And when the user tries to save to a place that they need privileges to write to, if they don't select another location and click cancel on the dialog my application crashes. How do I either prevent the crash, or attempt to elevate at startup?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what library or language you're using, but I would guess you could catch the exception, and try again? Maybe a loop that exits when the write succeeds or the user tells you they don't want to export after all?

Comment: I am using C++, sorry, forgot to put that as a tag. I am only using pure WinAPI. Everything is wrapped in a try-catch statement, and on exception shows an error message saying the export could not be done. If `GetSaveFileName()` returns false, meaning the user canceled, I just should have used `return;` but I used `throw;`. So that is fixed. But in WinAPI C++ how could attempt to elevate permissions on startup? And if the user could not authenticate as administrator, would my application still be able to run?

Comment: @BrandonMiller: you cannot invoke UAC on startup manually. The OS loader handles that before the process even starts running. Like Kate said, you have to re-design your app to work with UAC elevation. If your app does not require elevation on startup, but does require running a particular task elevated, you must separate that task into its own process so the OS can elevate it as needed. Either move the task into a separate EXE and run it with `ShellExecute/Ex()` using the "runas" verb, or move it into a COM object that you can instantiate with the COM Elevation Moniker.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the Drive and select Properties, then go to Security tab, and click Edit.
2. A new window will open, now under “Group and User Names”, select the user from the list whom you want to deny / allow access to a specific folder, now under “Permissions for Users” check the Deny / Allow checkbox next to Modify (all other checkbox will get ticked automatically).
3. Click OK and then click Yes when a Windows Security window will pops-up.
4. Now click OK again and you are done

Comment: Suggest this question and Answer is moved to SuperUser?